# Batch - Checking if directory doesn't exist doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have the following Batch-Script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SET directoryContainsFiles=%~f1

ECHO %directoryContainsFiles%

IF NOT EXIST directoryContainsFiles (
    ECHO "ERROR: 1. Argument -> Directory which should contain source files not found!"
    EXIT /B 1
)
```

When I run the command 
`rename_media_files.cmd "G:\Projects\Rename Batch Script\testfolder\source"` 
(on cmd.exe - Windows 10 64 bit) with an directory that definitely exists the `directoryContainsFiles` gets `echo`d correctly (`G:\Projects\Rename Batch Script\testfolder\source`) but the `IF NOT EXIST` clause doesn't work because i allways get the error messsage inside: `ERROR: 1. Argument ...`.

I also tried calling the script with an ending backslash in the directory path:
`rename_media_files.cmd "G:\Projects\Rename Batch Script\testfolder\source\"`

I also tried (with and without ending backslash) to check for a nul file:
`IF NOT EXIST directoryContainsFiles/nul`.

What is wrong?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Since the directoryname contains a separator (space(s)) you need to "quote the name" and since `directoryContainsFiles` is the name of a *variable* then you need `IF NOT EXIST "%directoryContainsFiles%" (` or preferably `IF NOT EXIST "%directoryContainsFiles%\." (` where the `%varname%` delivers the contents of the variable. The second form I've shown detects a *directory*. The first detects a *file OR directory*. You code was attempting to detect a directory (or file) named literally `directoryContainsFiles` - which I'd assume does *not* exist.

Comment: @Magoo, the trailing dot in `if not exist "%directoryContainsFiles%\."` must be removed in order to check for existing directory...

Comment: @aschipfl : OOh - well spotted! right you are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this modification:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SET "directoryContainsFiles=%~f1"

ECHO=%directoryContainsFiles%

IF NOT EXIST "%directoryContainsFiles%\" (
    ECHO "ERROR: 1. Argument -> Directory which should contain source files not found!"
    EXIT /B 1
)
```

However I see no reason to `SET` a variable in the first place:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
ECHO=%~f1
IF NOT EXIST "%~f1\" (
    ECHO "ERROR: 1. Argument -> Directory which should contain source files not found!"
    EXIT /B 1
)
```